# How to setup allure?

Tags: python, pytest, allure

Today I try to use pytest with allure . after i installed the allure and want to check the version.

'allure --version' is not work.

```
$ allure --version
```

result:

```
{}
io.airlift.airline.ParseArgumentsUnexpectedException: Found unexpected parameters: [--version]
at io.airlift.airline.Cli.validate(Cli.java:148)
at io.airlift.airline.Cli.parse(Cli.java:116)
at io.airlift.airline.Cli.parse(Cli.java:97)
at ru.yandex.qatools.allure.CommandLine.main(CommandLine.java:44)
```

Comment: What makes you think that this is a problem? I'd assume that there is (as stated in the error message) no such parameter

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling allure? Share your environment details. And how did you install allure?
If you are using mac, installing allure with brew works fine.